# Function to handle multiple existing independent data definitions

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I have multiple data definitions, as an easy example:

```
data Fruit = Apple String Bool
            | Cherry String String
            | Grape String

data Vegetable = Carrot String
                | Onion Bool String
                | Tomato String String
```

Now I want to have a function which should proceed both types and I tried something like this:

```
f :: a -> String
f (Carrot s) = s
f (Apple s b) = s
f (Onion b s) = s
...
```

But this is not working because the expected type `a` cannot be matched with for example the type `Carrot`. I want to know how I should define a function which can handle multiple existing independent data definitions with the help of pattern matching or other techniques.

Comment: You can define an `f :: Either Fruit Vegetable -> String`, or you can define a typeclass (and define two `f`s).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the hints. Am I right that `Either` is only working with two types?

Comment: no with one type, the `Either Fruit Vegetable` type. So you then write `f (Left (Apple s b)) = ...`, `f (Right (Carrot c)) = ...`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem great idea too, you could post it even as an answer, now I’m thinking, is my answer equivalent at what you say?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A way to do what you are trying to do is with a new data type that involves both foods, so, lets call it Food, it would be:

```
data Food = Veg Vegetable | Fr Fruit deriving Show

data Fruit = Apple String Bool
            | Cherry String String
            | Grape String deriving Show

data Vegetable = Carrot String
                | Onion Bool String
                | Tomato String String deriving Show


f :: Food -> String
f (Veg v) = fVeg v
f (Fr f) = fFruit f

fVeg (Carrot s) = s
fVeg (Onion b s) = s
fVeg (Tomato s1 s2) = s1 ++ s2

fFruit (Apple s b) = s
...
...

  f $ Veg $ Onion True "friend"
=> "friend"
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Very clean solution without changing existing types.

Comment: @ClaudioP no problem! I have always loved to help, I hope you accept one of the two answers :)

Answer (score 5):

There are two options. One It is what Damian Lattenero says,  Another option, on the other hand is to use typeclasses.

```
class Food a where
   f :: a -> String

instance Food Fruit where
    f (Apple ...) = ...
    f (Cherry ...) = ...
    f ...

instance Food Vegetable where
    f (Carrot ...) = ...
    f (Onion ...) = ...
    f (Tomato ...) = ...
```

The problem with that is that you cannot have, for instance, a list of Food, because Fruit and Vegetable are of different types. But you can use f for both types without problem.

EDIT:

Another option, existential quantification, to have both types in a list, but only applying f to the data (using also the code above):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data F = forall a. (Food a) => F a

instance Food F where
    f (F x) = f x

xs :: [F]
xs = [F (Apple ...), F (Carrot ..), F (Tomato ...)]
```

And an example of a function using f:

```
mapF :: [F] -> [String]
mapF xs = map f xs
```

Comment: Note that typeclasses+existstentials often lead to a [known antipattern](https://lukepalmer.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/haskell-antipattern-existential-typeclass/)